# How to append a value with first Z index of translate3d

Tags: jquery

I try to implement carousel in my website from

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html
Problem is that , in second scrolling on words the sixth item become broken..so i need to append Z index of translate3d() with -70  in its j query

```
if (slider.transitions) {
    target = (vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + target + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)";
    dur = (dur !== undefined) ? (dur/1000) + "s" : "0s";
    slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);
     slider.container.css("transition-duration", dur);
  }
```

i need to *target+(-70)*append in "translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)";
How can i do this?

Comment: where exactly in `"translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)"`?

Comment: this is inside the plugin Jquery file , used to slide the carousel.when it run first it set in  css as  ,transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); In scond scrolling transform: translate3d(-2948px, 0px, 0px); ans so on  I need to set all z index other than first add with -70

Comment: you want to change target to target minus 70px?

Comment: try changing this: `"translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)"` to this `"translate3d(" + (target-70) + ",0,0)"`

Comment: Thank u for the effort .I try it , But it make the next and prev arrows dont work. i try  target = target +~70;  too but this to make the slider effect hide

Comment: why do you need to modify this the slider is responsive?

Comment: This is incomplete code making a confusion. Please put it at fiddle. Consider that you must show how and where you are using target variable. In given code you are setting it but not using